# Rule Word Sections in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to control footer in Word file via Excel VBA.

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim Sec

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True

Set Sec = objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add
```

I get "Object does'not support this property or method." alert

Where am I wrong.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Microsoft Word XX.0 Object Library (I am on 16) from Tools > References in the VBA IDE

```
Sub createWordAddFooter()

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    
    Set objWord = New Word.Application
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = True
    
    objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add


End Sub
```

Comment: Or use late binding and add `Const wdHeaderFooterPrimary As Long = 1` to the original code.